# Django: counting tags of contents that match a query

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I need to build a query in Django, and I feel I'm a little bit over my head here, any help is a ppreciated.
I have Contents and Tags, with a relationship table between them:

```
class Content(mixins.TracketEntity):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)
    data = jsonfield.JSONField()

class Tag(mixins.TracketEntity):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)

class ContentTag(models.Model):
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
```

Now, I can filter contents by title, for example, like so:

```
content_query = Content.objects.filter(title__icontains="matematica")
```

That will give a list of contents, say:

- Matematica basica
- Matematica pura
- Matematica aplicada
- Matematica avancada

And say these contents have these tags:

- Matematica basica. Tags = MATEMATICA, EASY
- Matematica pura. Tags = MATEMATICA
- Matematica aplicada. Tags = MATEMATICA, HARD
- Matematica avancada. Tags = MATEMATICA, HARD

Given that scenario, how do I build a Django query that will return a list of Tags associated with the Contents of content_query, along with the content count of each one?
The expected result set for that query would be:

- MATEMATICA, 4
- EASY, 1
- HARD, 2

Also, this kind of query will be ran all the time on the database (Postgres).
What indices should I add on the database to make it perform decently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can fairly simply do this in a single query, via aggregation:

```
from django.db.models import Count
tags = (Tag.objects
        .filter(content__title__icontains='matematica')
        .values('name')
        .annotate(tag_count=Count('tag')))
```

In order to make this work, you need to add a `ManyToMany` declaration on `Tag` that uses the existing through-table, `ContentTag`:

```
content = models.ManyToManyField('Content', through='ContentTag')
```

Because the through-table already exists, this won't change your database at all.

Comment: Thanks a million. You just saved our day sir :-)

Answer (score 0):

Get all tags related to `Content` instances that title contains "matematica"

```
tags = Content.objects.filter(title__icontains="matematica").tags.all()
```

Then, count tags.

```
result_dict = {}
for tag in tags:
    result_dict[tag.name] +=1
```